# remove specific characters from a string

Tags: scripting, shell, shell-script, sed, awk

I need to replace spaces with comma and then remove certain extra specific chars from a string.

```
echo "$d"
>>Mon Apr 22 05:06:00 UTC 2019
jent=$(echo $jt1 | sed 's/[[:space:]]/,/g')
echo "$jent"
>>Mon,Apr,22,05:06:00,UTC,2019 #this does the first job of replacing the space with comma
```

But again I want to remove the UTC part and the comma before it, how can I achieve it?

desired output should be

```
Mon,Apr,22,05:06:00,2019
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with one sed call, e.g.

```
$ echo "Mon Apr 22 05:06:00 UTC 2019" | sed 's/ \(UTC \)\?/,/g'
Mon,Apr,22,05:06:00,2019
```

Comment: Note that `\?` is a GNU extension, you can replace it with `\{0,1\}` for better portability.

Answer (score 1):

Since your date has standard output and fix number of columns you can use awk to print the wanted data

```
[user@server1 ~]$ echo "Mon Apr 22 05:06:00 UTC 2019" | awk '{print $1","$2","$3","$4","$6}'
Mon,Apr,22,05:06:00,2019
```

Comment: or `awk -v OFS=, '{print $1,$2,$3,$4,$6}'`

Answer (score 0):

You can simply say:

```
~]$ export jent="$(echo $jent | sed 's/,UTC//g')"
~]$ echo $jent
Mon,Apr,22,05:06:00,2019
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with translate command:

```
jent=$(echo "$d" | tr -ds  UTC "  " | tr " " ,)
# the first double quotes contains two spaces 
echo "$jent"
Mon,Apr,22,05:06:00,2019
```

Comment: That's not how `tr` works. That would change `Tue` to  `ue` for instance.

Answer (score 0):

I have done by below method using awk and sed.

command:

```
echo "Mon Apr 22 05:06:00 UTC 2019"|awk '{$(NF-1)="";print $0}'| sed -r "s/\s+/ /g"| sed "s/ /,/g"
```

output:

```
Mon,Apr,22,05:06:00,2019
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always do one substitution after the other  in one `sed` invocation:

```
$ echo "Mon Apr 22 05:06:00 UTC 2019" | sed 's/ \{1,\}/,/g; s/,UTC,/,/'
Mon,Apr,22,05:06:00,2019
```

The `\{1,\}` is to cover the case where the day is padded to width 2 in the input as in:

```
$ echo "Mon Apr  2 05:06:00 UTC 2019" | sed 's/ \{1,\}/,/g; s/,UTC,/,/'
Mon,Apr,2,05:06:00,2019
```

Note that if it's to process the output of `date`, you could tell `date` to output in the format you want to start with:

```
$ LC_ALL=C date -u +%a,%b,%-d,%T,%Y
Thu,Apr,25,11:47:25,2019
```

`%-d` (to avoid the padding) is not standard but pretty common.